# Bitfinex REST API: how to check active orders until active, then check historical orders after executed or canceled in one script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, orders

I'll like to get order info after order execution, but when I look for active orders, the order is ACTIVE, but when I cancel the order on exchange the script exits with historical order list, but not with the recent one. If I run script again and look for recent order.id in historical orders then I see it CANCELED. How to do it in one check?

```
const bitfinexHistoricalOrders = new RESTv2(userConfig.bitfinex.h_orders)
const bitfinexActiveOrders = new RESTv2(userConfig.bitfinex.a_orders)
const bitfinexBuy = new RESTv2(userConfig.bitfinex.buy)
const START = Date.now() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000) // 1 day
let pair = 'BTCUSD'
let orderID = 35448795794

function CheckBitfinexOrderManual(pair, orderID) {
    bitfinexActiveOrders.activeOrders().then(orders => {
        if (orders.length > 0) {
            for (const o of orders) {
                console.log(o.id, o.status)
                if (o.status === 'ACTIVE' && o.id === orderID) {
                    log(logSymbols.warning, chalk.gray(`${chalk.green('Bitfinex')} manual order ${o.id} not yet filled`))
                }
            }
        } else if (!orders.length) {
            CheckBitfinexOrderManualH(pair, orderID)
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(`${chalk.green('Bitfinex')} error of manual Active Orders: ${err}`)
        return
    })
}
function CheckBitfinexOrderManualH(pair, orderID) {
    bitfinexHistoricalOrders.orderHistory(`t${pair}`, START, END, 10, (error, history) => {
        for (const h of history) {
            console.log(h.id, h.amountOrig, h.status)
            if (h.id === orderID && h.status.includes('EXECUTED')) {
                log(logSymbols.success, chalk.gray(`${chalk.green('Bitfinex')} manual LIMIT order ${h.id} filled`))
                return
            } else if (h.id === orderID && h.status.includes('PARTIALLY FILLED')) {
                log(logSymbols.success, chalk.gray(`${chalk.green('Bitfinex')} manual LIMIT order ${h.id} partially filled`))
                return
            } else if (h.id === orderID && h.status.includes('CANCELED')) {
                log(logSymbols.success, chalk.gray(`${chalk.green('Bitfinex')} manual LIMIT order ${h.id} canceled`))
                return
            }
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        log(logSymbols.error, `${chalk.green('Bitfinex')} check manual LIMIT order API error ${err}`)
        return
    })
}
const buy = new Order({
    cid: Date.now(),
    type: Order.type.EXCHANGE_LIMIT, //EXCHANGE_FOK,
    symbol: `tBTCUSD`,
    amount: 0.01,
    price: 6500,
    tif: moment().add(30, 'minutes').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') //TimeInForce 30 minutes
}, bitfinexBuy)
buy.submit().then(() => {
    log(logSymbols.success, chalk.grey(`${chalk.green('Bitfinex')} manual buy LIMIT order ${buy.id} set.`))
    orderID = buy.id
    setTimeout(CheckBitfinexOrderManual, 10000, pair, buy.id)
    setTimeout(CheckBitfinexOrderManualH, 10000, pair, buy.id)
}).catch((err) => {
    log(logSymbols.error, `${chalk.green('Bitfinex')} manual buy LIMIT error ${err.message}`)
    return
})
```

Binance `allOrders` have everything in one (active and else).

Answer (score 1):

They don't have an endpoint that gives you both active and historic orders, but you could keep track of your orders using WebSocket. With a WebSocket connection you get a snapshot of your open orders when you open a connection and updates when anything changes: https://docs.bitfinex.com/reference#ws-auth-orders

Comment: I'm asking about REST method and why my script is not capable of my intentions...